# How exactly does an NSView, an NSViewController, and MainMenu.xib fit together?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, nsview, nib, nsviewcontroller

I'm going to cut right to the chase: my application has grown quite a bit, and now I think it's time for me to do some tidying up. I want to separate some of my views from my MainMenu.xib file into their own Nib file. The part that's tripping me up is the whole "Interface Builder + My Code" thing. Here's what I've done so far:

1. I've added a view controller proxy object:
   [image: View Controller object in Interface Builder object browser]
2. In the **Identity** inspector, I've added my view controller's class name to the Custom Class field.
   [image: Identity Inspector in Interface Builder]
3. In the **Attributes** inspector, I've entered the name of the Nib I want to load up.
   [image: Nib Name field in Interface Builder]
4. I've connected the view controller object's *view* outlet to an existing view in MainMenu.xib.
   [image: View Outlet on View Controller in Interface Builder]
5. Finally, I hit Cmd+R, and my view isn't there.
   [Insert image of FFFFUUUUU meme here.]

What am I missing? I've been staring at my Mac day-in and day-out for the last two weeks, so I wouldn't be surprised if I've completely left something out. If anyone sees my n00b ways and would be willing to point me in the right direction, I'd be really grateful. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "my view isn't there". What did you connect as an `IBOutlet` `view` then? You need to explicitly call `addSubview:` on whatever view you want to add your subview to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You almost got it.

I published a [demo-project](https://github.com/iluuu1994/ViewControllerTest) on Github, just for you ;)

---

Finally, you need to actually add the view to the window. Do this in your `AppDelegate`, 
or wherever you think is suitable.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.customViewController.view];
    [self.customViewController.view setFrame:[self.window.contentView bounds]];
}
```

Or course, you first need to make an outlet for your view controller:

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet ITCustomViewController *customViewController;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, man! Maybe you should become the documentation writer and demo app creator for Apple. I don't know why everyone thinks Apple's documentation is so great. It's lacking in a lot of areas, and half the time, their demo apps use deprecated methods! I know SO doesn't like it when comments are used for "thanking people," but I don't care: Thanks for taking the time to help a fresh-faced Cocoa Maker, NSAddict!

Comment: @BenStock Apple documentation actually IS pretty great, they just cover a bit more in-depth stuff. But I agree with you that they aren't a lot of help when you're trying to get going with Cocoa. Back when I started developing with ObjC, I thought this [Youtube-Channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/AppleProgramming) pretty useful.